# May I estimate the camera pose relative to multiple-marker board based on coordinates of centers of markres?

Tags: augmented-reality

I have implemented an algorithm combined of mean-shift tracker and FAST detector to track multiple-marker board as a part of augmented reality project.

Is there any way to estimate the camera pose relative to the multiple-marker board based on the coordinates of centers of markers without accurate knowledge about coordinates of their corners?

Comment: "without accurate knowledge about coordinates of their corners" - I don't understand. If you have the marker-board in your scene-reconstruction how can you not know the coordinates (in some world-space) of the corners?

Comment: My algorithm depends on mean-shift tracker. I have a bounding box around each marker and track the marker by shifting the mean of the coordinates of keypoints which are contained in the bounding box. So, the coordinates of centers of markers are known accurately. But the coordinates of the bounding box I have are far away from the right coordinates of markers' corners. Is that clear for you??